# Illegal instruction when trying to write linked list pointers in memory buffer

Tags: c, clang

I've got a block of memory I allocated, and I'm trying to divide it into blocks of a specific size, using a linked list to track them. The block size is arbitrary, so I'm using a `unsigned char*` as my buffer pointer.

The problem is when I get to the start of a block, and I try to cast the pointer to anything larger than that `unsigned char*` in order to write a pointer value. Every variation I try leads to a runtime `Illegal instruction`. The only variation that didn't fail is when I change my buffer pointer to be a struct containing a `next` pointer field, and then set that `next` pointer directly. But that leads to iterating over the buffer in chunks of that struct size, which doesn't line up with the desired block size.

What is the "correct" way to do this without running into these cast issues?

**Edit:** Added simplified code to show issue.

```
uint32_t maxMessageSize = 123;
uint32_t maxMessages = 5000;

uint8_t* messageBuffer;
uint32_t messageBufferSize = maxMessageSize * maxMessages;

messageBuffer = (uint8_t*)malloc( messageBufferSize );
memset( messageBuffer, 0, messageBufferSize );
uint32_t bufferOffset = 0;
while ( bufferOffset < messageBufferSize - maxMessageSize ) {
    uint32_t nextOffset = bufferOffset + maxMessageSize;
    intptr_t** messagePointerToNext = (intptr_t**)&messageBuffer[bufferOffset];
    *messagePointerToNext = (intptr_t*)&messageBuffer[nextOffset];
    bufferOffset = nextOffset;
}
```

Comment: Don't describe the code. **show** the code.

Comment: Without code to look at, it sounds like you're hitting address alignment issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C 2018 6.2.8 1 says:

> Complete object types have alignment requirements which place restrictions on the addresses at which objects of that type may be allocated. An alignment is an implementation-defined integer value representing the number of bytes between successive addresses at which a given object can be allocated. An object type imposes an alignment requirement on every object of that type…

From your description, it sounds like you are not maintaining the alignment required for the objects being used with your allocator. This results in attempting to access an object without the alignment it requires, resulting in a hardware exception.

Memory allocators often deal with this by ensuring that every pointer they return is allocated to a multiple of some fundamental alignment that serves for all supported objects, such as 16 bytes. (Or, for allocations smaller than the fundamental alignment, this may be relaxed to an alignment suitable for all possible objects that might fit in the requested space.)

Another approach is for the allocator to accept both a requested size and a requested alignment, such as `mymalloc(10 * 8, 4)` to request space for 10 items of size 8 bytes each of which requires alignment to a multiple of 4 bytes.

You can obtain the alignment required for an object type with `_Alignof(type)`, such as `_Alignof(double)`.

Comment: I think this is probably the cause, I didn't know it was an actual error to point to unaligned data...